# CentOS Linux console command versus PHP exec(command)

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos6

I have a C program that I wrote called `convert3to5`, originally written for CentOS / Fedora 32bit system in early 2010. I am moving it to new CentOS 6.x 64bit system host.

From a CentOS Putty console I can run the `convert3to5` command just fine; here is a sample of it running from my console:

```
[root@cloud convert3to5]# ls
CircleStar  convert3to5  Convert3To5.txt  test.tif 
[root@cloud convert3to5]# ./convert3to5 /var/www/webadmin/data/www/mydomain.com/uploads/SV-DIS160217B.tif  
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, /var/www/webadmin/data/www/mydomain.com/uploads/SV-DIS160217B.tif: wrong data type 7 for "RichTIFFIPTC"; tag ignored. Image has an undefined fillorder - using default: MSB2LSB
```

The above is a normal completion of convert3to5 and I get a `SV-DIS160217B.bmp` that is placed in `/var/www/webadmin/data/www/mydomain.com/uploads/` So **running it from console works fine**.

Question - I am attempting to run the same exact command from PHP using the `exec(command, output, return)` command as follows:

```
chdir($sv_path.$c3to5_path);    //change our working directory to "/convert3to5" directory
$command = "./convert3to5 $targetFile 2>&1";
$result = exec($command, $output, $return);
// the output of the above command - is a .bmp file it will be placed in the same path as the input .tif file
```

I get the following $result:

> ERROR: Unable to convert
>   /var/www/webadmin/data/www/mydomain.com/uploads/SV-DIS160217B.tif to 5
>   color BMP file: Open file Error: Tiff_3_to_BMP_5_.lut!

My convert3to5 does need to open `Tiff_3_to_BMP_5_.lut`

Why does it find `Tiff_3_to_BMP_5_.lut` when I run `convert3to5` from a console prompt but not from PHP exec(...) in both cases my pwd shows that I am in

```
[root@cloud convert3to5]# pwd 
/var/www/webadmin/data/www/mydomain.com/myView/convert3to5
```

I have also verified pwd is correct from my PHP script after the

```
chdir($sv_path.$c3to5_path);
```

Tiff_3_to_BMP_5_.lut is in CircleStar directory - the path to CircleStar is `/var/www/webadmin/data/www/mydomain.com/myView/convert3to5/CircleStar`

**Summary: ./convert3to5 works while PHP exec('convert3to5 ..) does not appear to work.**

Can anyone suggest the difference and how to fix and/or debug?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my above comment to wonton:

From the console I was running as root (so fully privileged). I supposed my PHP script will run as the "apache" user on the server?

Here was the problem I believe: I looked at the CircleStar directory privileges where the `Tiff_3_to_BMP_5_.lut` file exists. CircleStar had `rw-r--r--` (0644) when running as root from console this allowed my convert3to5 program to find and open `Tiff_3_to_BMP_5_.lut` file just fine. However not the PHP exec(...) once I changed the privilege on CircleStar to `rwxr-xr-x` (0755) PHP exec(...) ran fine!

So ultimately it was a permission issue.

Answer (score 1):

You're running the console from the convert3to5 directory, and I suspect your old C program used a relative path to the .lut file, possible relative to the .tif?

What if in the console example you did

```
cd ../..
./path/to/convert3to5/convert3to5 /var/www/webadmin/data/www/mydomain.com/uploads/SV-DIS160217B.tif
```

Might be related to $targetFile. Print that and see if it's the full path.

Finally, run

```
/full/path/to/convert3to5 fullTargetPath
```

If that works, then as a workaround, if you just do `exec('/full/path/to/convert3to5 $fullTargetPath, ..)` it should behave like the console.

Comment: thanks for the info; I figured out the problem. from the console I was running login as root (so full privilege). From my PHP backend script  I suppose it runs as "apache" user? Here was the problem I believe: I looked at the CircleStar directory privileges where Tiff_3_to_BMP_5_.lut file exist. CircleStar had rw-r--r-- (0644) when running as root from console this allowed my convert3to5 program to find Tiff_3_to_BMP_5_.lut file just fine. However not the PHP exec(...) once I changed the privilege on CircleStar to rwxr-xr-x PHP exec(...) ran fine!

Comment: glad you figured it out!